# Write CanDeactivate function in the same component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In angular 2 RC5 router 3.0.0 RC1 I would like to call the `canDeactivate` function from within the same component (or at least the same file) the router is checking meaning:

```
{ path: 'componentPath', component: MyComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] }
```

With `CanDeactivateGuard` being either in the same file as `MyComponent` or, even better, `CanDeactivateGuard` could be `MyComponent` and the `canDeactivate()` function be inside `MyComponent` (but I'm not sure it's possible)

I've tried the following route:

```
{ path: 'componentPath', component: MyComponent, canDeactivate: [MyComponent] }
```

And in `MyComponent`:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: 'MyComponent.html',
    directives: []
})

export interface CanDeactivateComponent {
    canDeactivate: () => boolean | Observable<boolean>;
}


export class MyComponent implements OnInit, CanDeactivate<CanDeactivateComponent>  {

    onInit(){
        // MyComponent initialization 
    }

    canDeactivate(component: CanDeactivateComponent): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        console.log('test');
        return true;
    }


}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
index:2 Error: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent: (?, ?)
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can just implement CanDeactivate from '@angular/router'

```
canDeactivate(component: MyComponente, route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return true;
}
```

i dont think you need the canDeactivate in the router config if you go like this.

important edit: this is RC5, i dont know if it also works in RC1

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough...I'm using angular RC5 and router RC1! I will try that a little bit later

Comment: Can you be a little biut more explicit on how to do it? How can I call the component in `canDeactivate` while this function is supposed to be inside the component?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's time consuming, but still, upgrade to RC.5 and use route guards. I described them in this blog (it uses RC4): https://yakovfain.com/2016/07/20/angular-2-guarding-routes/

The RC.5 version of the code samples from that blog is here: 
https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/tree/master/chapter3/router_samples/app

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough...I'm using angular RC5 and router RC1! I'm trying to use the guard in a different way, please see the question